# If I create an application on Facebook does it also need a front end on my home website?

Tags: facebook

If I create an application on Facebook that populates the canvas / iframe on Facebook, do I have to have anything on the home domain that also works?  For example, if I have myapp.com do I need an interface on that page that operates independent of facebook for any reason or can I just use my home domain to serve the php files for the iframe in facebook?  Also, is there any reason I can't have a separate set of webpages not in facebook that introduce the app, about, contact us, etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will run from your webserver but doesn't have any requirements for showing anything directly from your website.  In other words you could create a directory on your webserver and isolate your app.

I'm not aware of any limitations discussing your app in your website but a quick glance over the FB terms of service might highlight anything specific you're trying to do.